# SQL Query Using Minus/Not Exists

Tags: mysql, sql, querying

I want to query this statement:

```
Drinkers who do not frequent the bar Henrys
```

Now, I know I cant use a simple query like this:

```
SELECT dinker
FROM frequents
WHERE bar <> 'Henrys';
```

because what if a person goes to Henrys bar and also frequents other bars as well? This person will still be included in the result. This query only filters out the people who only frequent Henrys bar and nothing else.

I tried to use the MINUS operator, but in MySQL it doesn't seem to support the query:

```
SELECT drinker 
FROM frequents
MINUS
SELECT drinker
FROM frequents
Where bar = 'Henrys';
```

I want to try and rewrite this using NOT EXISTS, but can't seem to get it to work or correctly think through the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select drinker
  from frequents f
 where not exists (select 1
          from frequents x
         where x.drinker = f.drinker
           and x.bar = 'Henrys');
```

Comment: Can you explain what "select 1" does?

Comment: an `exists` or `not exists` condition tests whether the subquery does or does not return row(s). As such, you can put anything in the select list. It doesn't change whether the subquery will or won't return rows, so its use as an exists or not exists subquery is not affected. Selecting 'x' or 'fish' or 'dog' would also work.

Answer (score 2):

Something to the effect of finding all of the drinkers that went to a Henry's Bar and then selecting the drinkers that are not part of that array

```
SELECT drinker
FROM frequents
WHERE drinker NOT IN (SELECT drinker FROM frequents WHERE bar = 'Henrys')
```